# how do i backup my shared preference code in my device memory android

Tags: android

in my code i have stored some values in shared preference and i retrieved in the same page.But now i need to backup all my shared preference value in my device memory.I referred some tutorials and i have got the code.But i don't know how to implement it.Please help me to backup my shared preference value.

```
    public class medicalinfo extends Activity {


    String namee,dobb,agee,heightt,weightt,lastt,nextt,Medicinee,allergies;
    Button submit;
    Button r,slide;
    Button logout;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String Name = "name";
    public static final String Dob= "dob";
    public static final String Age = "age";
    public static final String Height = "height";
    public static final String Weight = "weight";
    public static final String Last = "last";
    public static final String Next = "next";
    public static final String Medicine="medicine";
    public static final String Allergies = "allergies";

//    static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "prefs";



    EditText nam1,dob1,age1,height1,weight1,last1,medicine1,allergies1;

    String Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6,Value7,Value8,Value9,Value10,Value11,Value12,v,Value13,Value14,Value15,Value16,Value17;


    TimePicker myTimePicker;
    Button buttonstartSetDialog;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    final static int RQS_1 = 1;

    Calendar cale;

    private TextView pDisplayDate;
    private Button pPickDate;
    private int pYear;
    private int pMonth;
    private int pDay;
    /** This integer will uniquely define the dialog to be used for displaying date picker.*/
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;







    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;



    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;




    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    pYear = year;
                    pMonth = monthOfYear;
                    pDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                    //displayToast();
                }
            };



    /** Updates the date in the TextView */
    private void updateDisplay()  {
        try {
            pPickDate.setText(
                    new StringBuilder()
                            // Month is 0 based so add 1
                            .append(pDay).append("/")
                            .append(pMonth + 1).append("/")
                            // .append(pDay).append("/")
                            .append(pYear));
            String date1=new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(pDay).append("/")
                    .append(pMonth + 1).append("/")
                    //.append(pDay).append("-")
                    .append(pYear).toString();



            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();


            String currDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);


            System.out.println("&&&&&curr"+currDate);

            System.out.println("&&&&&pick"+date1);





            SimpleDateFormat formatter1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
            java.util.Date date2 = formatter1.parse(date1);
            java.util.Date date3 = formatter1.parse(currDate);

            System.out.println("&&&&&ggg"+date2);

            System.out.println("&&&&&gggcccccccc" +date3);

            if(date2.before(date3)){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the valid Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }







    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_medicalinfo);

        sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor=sharedpreferences.edit();


       /* SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 0);
        boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
        setSilent(silent);

*/

        //String nam1,dob1,age1,height1,weight1,last1,next1,medicine1,allergies1;

        //final EditText nam1,dob1,age1,height1,weight1,last1,next1,medicine1,allergies1;

        nam1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        dob1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.dob);
        age1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        height1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
        weight1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        last1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_visited);
        pPickDate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.next_visit);
        //  accno=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.bankaccno);
        medicine1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.regular_medicine);
        allergies1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.allergies);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit1);
        r=(Button) findViewById(R.id.r1);
        logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);



















        Value1 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        Value2 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Dob, ""));
        Value3 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Age, ""));
        Value4 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Height, ""));
        Value5 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Weight, ""));
        Value6 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Last, ""));
        Value7 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Next, ""));
        //Value8 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Accno, ""));
        Value9 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Medicine, ""));
        Value10 = (sharedpreferences.getString(Allergies, ""));

        System.out.println("@@Value1 :"+Value1);
        System.out.println("@@Value2 :"+Value2);
        System.out.println("@@Value3 :"+Value3);
        System.out.println("@@Value4 pass :"+Value7);


        //EditText mno,ano,lno,pno,lano,rno,passno,accno,saccno,caccno,odaccno,dno,cno,cerno,bno;

      //  EditText nam1,dob1,age1,height1,weight1,last1,next1,medicine1,allergies1;

        System.out.println("Date"+Value7);

        nam1.setText(""+Value1);
        dob1.setText(""+Value2);
        age1.setText(""+Value3);
        height1.setText(""+Value5);
        weight1.setText(""+Value4);
        last1.setText(""+Value6);

        //accno.setText(""+Value8);
        medicine1.setText(""+Value9);
        allergies1.setText(""+Value10);
        pPickDate.setText(""+Value7);

        slide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slide);

      //  saveSharedPreferencesToFile(File med);

        slide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(medicalinfo.this, logo.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_out_right, R.anim.pull_in_left);

                finish();
            }
        });


       // saveSharedPreferencesToFile(File;



/*
        slide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slide);
        slide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        });


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //  mDrawerLayout.setBackground(Color.parseColor("FFFFFF"));
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new medicalinfo.DrawerItemClickListener());


        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new medicalinfo.DrawerItemClickListener());
        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        */
/*getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);*//*



        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  */
/* host Activity *//*

                mDrawerLayout,         */
/* DrawerLayout object *//*

                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  */
/* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret *//*

                R.string.drawer_open,  */
/* "open drawe.r" description for accessibility *//*

                R.string.drawer_close  */
/* "close drawer" description for accessibility *//*

        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        View head = (View) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test, null);
        //mDrawerList.addHeaderView(head);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(medicalinfo.this, login.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_out_right, R.anim.pull_in_left);

            }
        });
        System.out.println("name222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222");



*/

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(medicalinfo.this,login .class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_out_right, R.anim.pull_in_left);

            }
        });














        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              //  String namee,dobb,agee,heightt,weightt,lastt,nextt,Medicinee,allergies;

            //    EditText nam1,dob1,age1,height1,weight1,last1,next1,medicine1,allergies1;

                namee = nam1.getText().toString();
                dobb=dob1.getText().toString();
                agee= age1.getText().toString();
                heightt = height1.getText().toString();
                weightt = weight1.getText().toString();
                lastt=last1.getText().toString();
                nextt=pPickDate.getText().toString();
                //    acc=accno.getText().toString();
                Medicinee=medicine1.getText().toString();
                allergies=allergies1.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"+allergies);

                editor.putString(Name, namee);
                editor.putString(Dob, dobb);
                editor.putString(Age, agee);
                editor.putString(Height, heightt);
                editor.putString(Weight, weightt);
                editor.putString(Last, lastt);
                editor.putString(Next, nextt);
                //editor.putString(Accno, acc);
                   editor.putString(Medicine, Medicinee);
                editor.putString(Allergies, allergies);


                System.out.println("ffffffffffff"+nextt);

                editor.commit();Toast.makeText(medicalinfo.this, "Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                SimpleDateFormat formatter1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
                try {

                    Calendar cale = Calendar.getInstance();

                    java.util.Date date2 = formatter1.parse(nextt);
                    System.out.println("LLLLLLLLLLLLL"+date2);

                  cale.setTime(date2);

                    //Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cale.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
                    cale.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
                    cale.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);



                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver1.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            cale.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
                    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    intent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
                    intent.putExtra("date", "pPickDate");
                    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cale.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);





/*
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver1.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cale.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours

                    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                    //  cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    //cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 15);
intent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
                    intent.putExtra("date", "pPickDate");
                    //intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

                    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cale.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
*/




                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




            }
        });





        pPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });


        Calendar cal;
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        pYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        pMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        pDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        System.out.println("***************");


       // updateDisplay();

       // String currDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);













        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

















    }




    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        pDateSetListener,
                        pYear, pMonth, pDay);
        }
        return null;



    }









    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        // Intent i = new Intent(info_values.this, home.class);

        startActivity(new Intent(medicalinfo.this,logo.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left,R.anim.push_out_right);
        finish();


    }

    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                medicalinfo.this,
                onTimeSetListener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                is24r);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");

        timePickerDialog.show();

    }

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
            = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            setAlarm(calSet);
        }};

    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

        textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                "\n\n***\n"
                        + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                        + "***\n");
```

Below is my code which i got for shared preference.And i don't know how to include that code in my java file and am not sure that code is correct or not..please help me to backup my shared preference value in my device's memory.

```
private boolean saveSharedPreferencesToFile(File dst) {
    boolean res = false;
    ObjectOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dst));
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        output.writeObject(sharedPreferences.getAll());

        res = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if (output != null) {
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return res;
}

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    private boolean loadSharedPreferencesFromFile(File src) {
        boolean res = false;
        ObjectInputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.clear();
            Map<String, ?> entries = (Map<String, ?>) input.readObject();
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : entries.entrySet()) {
                Object v = entry.getValue();
                String key = entry.getKey();

                if (v instanceof Boolean)
                    editor.putBoolean(key, ((Boolean) v).booleanValue());
                else if (v instanceof Float)
                    editor.putFloat(key, ((Float) v).floatValue());
                else if (v instanceof Integer)
                    editor.putInt(key, ((Integer) v).intValue());
                else if (v instanceof Long)
                    editor.putLong(key, ((Long) v).longValue());
                else if (v instanceof String)
                    editor.putString(key, ((String) v));
            }
            editor.commit();
            res = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if (input != null) {
                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add both methods at the end of your `medicalinfo` Activity, and calling `saveSharedPreferencedToFile` or `loadSavedPreferencesFromFile` by passing it a File.

You can create a File like this : `File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "shared-prefs.txt");` You'll need to pass the same file to write and to read in your device memory.

If you call it from outside an activity, you'll need to pass it a context to call `context.getFilesDir()` .

Comment: Thank u..Can u edit in my file and send i didnot get u

Comment: First, add the code you provided with the saveSharedPrefsToFile and loadSharedPrefsFromFile methods to your activity (spot your onCreate{ ... }, and paste it after.  In your onCreate, you have a "saveSharedPreferencesToFile(File med)" line. Replace it with : "saveSharedPreferencesToFile(new File(getFilesDir(), "shared-prefs.txt"); " this will save your SharedPrefs to a file everytime you'll launch your app. When you'll want to load it from this file, add this line : "loadSharedPreferencesFromFile(new File(getFilesDir(), "shared-prefs.txt"); "

Comment: Sir when i launched the activity i didn't get any file saved in my device memory..i had made the changes as u said above.

Comment: Data is saved in : internal_storage/Android/data/com.yourapp/

Comment: Only in rooted mobile,backup of data text will be visible?

Comment: how to store backup data in external storage (sd card) of mobile

Comment: Try to look at your internal storage (with any file explorer) then Android/data/com.yourapp/

Comment: Sorry sir..I didn't get any folder in my device memory

Comment: Try with this, it should save your file to download directory : (didn't tested but seems to work) String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS); saveSharedPreferencesToFile(new File(path));